# Oracle 12c function in the WITH clause of subquery

Tags: oracle

I have a problem with subquery in the WITH clause.

Oracle version: 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64b

```
WITH
  FUNCTION upper_string(p_string IN VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2
  IS
  BEGIN
    RETURN UPPER(p_string);
  END;
SELECT upper_string AS ret_val
FROM dual;
```

I am getting

> PLS-103: Encoutered the symbol "end-of-file"...

Any guess where is the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your select you do not pass parameter to the function.

```
 SELECT upper_string('something to upper') AS ret_val
   FROM dual;
```

But the error probably states that you are in old environment, that does not support syntax of 12c.

Comment: You are right about the parameter (my bad).

What do you mean by an "old envirionment", how should I understand it?

Comment: May be oracle client 9i, sqlplus 9i, or your tool.

Comment: After adding parameter to your function, I ran query without any problem in sqlplus 12c, and TOAD, but in sqlplus 11g it gives the same exact error as yours - `ORA-06553: PLS-103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting...`

Comment: So the old version of sqlplus is the root cause of the problem. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/with-clause-enhancements-12cr1) you can find some infos about enhancements for WITH clause. You may try to use:

```
WITH
  FUNCTION upper_string(p_string IN VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2
  IS
  BEGIN
    RETURN UPPER(p_string);
  END;
SELECT upper_string AS ret_val
FROM dual
/
```

Comment: You forgot the argument: `ORA-06553: PLS-306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'UPPER_STRING'`